# Combinatorics with different length pieces

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let us say that we have different lengths of wood all of the same width and height we are trying to figure out how many different combinations of different lengths could fit in a given maximum length.

For example let us assumed that the length maximum is 100 units and we have access to 25 units of every size up to 100. Of course we could only fit one size of 100 in a length of 100 so we would not actually use the 25 but once. However in lengths of four would fit 25 times and therefore would qualify. 24 lengths of four and a length of five would exceed the maximum length allowed. However 23 length of four and a length of five would be allowed.

I am attempting to see how many different combinations there are where the order is actually important. So in that last example with a different positions for the length of five would mean a total of 24 possible locations.

I am unaware of any combinations calculator or formula that accounts for the lengths of different sized items like this.

As a semi truck driver this actually has a real world application for cargo storage and could help me get into a statistics position inside my company if I was able to answer this.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Awkward that comes so close to my needs, but more importantly I think I may have an NP-Easy method for an NP-Hard or even NP-Complete problem. My problem is it resolves a 3D version of my true issue with a linear version... If only the 3D variant applied! But this also means I need a peer review and potentially a publishing partner...

Comment: Also thanks, you inspired me and now I know the answer to my own question is literally a form of binary where the minimum length is a string of four zeros or four ones. I will ponder how to formulate that but it eliminates a number of possibilities from the start such as column two to column four and the same at the back. I'm getting closer.